# Rotate vim buffers through all open splits

Tags: vim, split, buffer

How does one rotate all currently visible open buffers through all splits?   (The exact direction of the rotation is not critically important to me, although it would be nice to have a few choices.)   I'm looking for something like Ctrl-Wr which works on strictly horizontal and vertical splits, but does not rotate "through" both.   Imagine one vertical split and one or both of those splits being horizontally split.

e.g., given:

```
----------------------------
  buffer a   |    buffer b
----------------------------
  buffer d   |    buffer c
----------------------------


The command should rotate the buffers to the following split windows(e.g.):

----------------------------
buffer d     |   buffer a
----------------------------
buffer c     |   buffer b
----------------------------
```

I would think something like that in general should be simple.   I understand the complexities of determining what clockwise means in this context, but would be perfectly happy with any definition.   Imagine that the buffers are all stored in a stack (which they probably are), I'd be perfectly happy to just pop the top one off the stack and push it to the bottom.

A command to rotate through vertical splits would also work:

```
----------------------------
  buffer a   |    buffer b
----------------------------
  buffer d   |    buffer c
----------------------------

to:

----------------------------
  buffer b   |    buffer a
----------------------------
  buffer c   |    buffer d
----------------------------
```

Even any way to move buffers across vertical splits in the presence of horizontal splits would be helpful.   I've tried all the Ctrl W options I could find, searched high and wide, and asked the LLMs.     (I haven't looked at the source yet, or options related to manipulating buffers directly.)

Comment: Indeed very simple: go over the list of windows and in each take the buffer from the next window in the list.

Comment: So… what did *you* try?

Comment: Is the question clear?    I would also be happy if I could just swap across vertical splits, like this:

a  |  b
c  |  d

then i hit Ctrl w?  and have:

b  |  a    \n
d  |  c

because then Ctrl-wr could then:

d  |  a    \n
b  |  c

(\n is for newline)
Does this make sense?    Is the problem with the question somehow related to the clarity of the question?    I would think this would be a ubiquitous need.

Comment: I'm a regular user, not a moderator, and I downvoted your question because it is just another low-effort "do it for me" one. Another user gave you a hint. What did you do with it?

Comment: Dear @rominl   I didn't understand the hint.    svlasov said, "Indeed very simple:  go over the list of windows..."     I replied that I didn't know what that meant.   Now I do not see that comment, which seems very strange to me.    Was it deleted for some reason? I also tried to figure out how to do this.    If your reply is for me to read the fine manual, it sure would be nice to provide the index where I should look, because I most certainly have been looking and disagree profoundly with your low effort comment.    Do you know how to do it?   If it is such low effort, why not tell me?

Comment: @svlasov   are you saying go into each split?   if so, that is not what i am looking for.    I'm looking for a "rotate all".    something that moves all the buffers through all the splits with one command.   i don't think the feature exists at this point, so I am thinking about writing it or using a plugin or something.

Comment: No, there is no built-in feature. But you can write a script that iterates over all windows. To list all windows: `:echo range(1, winnr('$'))`. To get the buffer number in that window: `:echo winbufnr(<winnr>)`. To switch to a window: `:<winnr>wincmd w`. To change buffer: `buffer <bufnr>`.

Comment: Thanks @svlasov .   That all seems to work.    I will post an answer with what I did.    If you doublecheck the answer and create an improved version I will accept your answer and delete mine.

Comment: @user3761340, No need for a separate answer, yours is a very good one.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following to the _vimrc creates the requested feature and binds it to Ctrl-w Ctrl-a

```
function! RotateBuffers()
    " Get the total number of windows
    let totalWindows = winnr('$')

    " If there's only one window, no rotation needed
    if totalWindows == 1
        return
    endif

    " Get the buffer number of the first window
    let firstBuf = winbufnr(1)

    " Iterate over windows starting from the second window
    for winNum in range(2, totalWindows)

        " Get the buffer number for winNum
        let bufNum = winbufnr(winNum)

        " Move to the previous window
        execute (winNum - 1) . 'wincmd w'

        " Set the buffer of the previous window to the current window's buffer
        execute 'buffer ' . bufNum
    endfor

    " Set the buffer of the last window to the buffer of the first window
    execute totalWindows . 'wincmd w'
    execute 'buffer ' . firstBuf
endfunction

" Call the function
call RotateBuffers()


nnoremap <C-W><C-A> :call RotateBuffers()<CR>
```

Comment: Well done. This can be removed: `execute winNum . 'wincmd w " Switch to the window`, no need to switch window to get its buffer. `" Get the buffer number for the current window` - the comment is incorrect, you actually get buffer for `winNum`.

Comment: Thanks.   I made the edits you suggested.   I have a couple issues I've noticed (which occur both with and without the edits):
```
1.  sometimes i have to execute Ctrl-w Ctrl-a    twice before it takes
2.  if the buffers have been modified and not yet written i get an error message:

"Error detected while processing function RotateBuffers--E37 No write since last change (add ! to override)"
```

Also, there is an error in returning to the original split.    I will continue working on it.

Comment: 1. I would put some `echomsg` and try to debug it, but I don't see any obvious problems with the code. 2. You need to `set hidden` to allow hiding unsaved buffers.